# How to get attribute value of node in xml using xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to get the value of attribute name of all the nodes. my xml is

```
<branches>
    <branch-area name="abc">
        <branch>
            <branch-name> xyz Street</branch-name>
        </branch>
    </branch-area>
    <branch-area name="def 11">
        <branch>
            <branch-name>pqr</branch-name>
        </branch>
    </branch-area>
    <branch-area name="ghi 14">
        <branch>
            <branch-name>jkl</branch-name>
        </branch>
    </branch-area>
</branches>
```

for that i am using below code

```
String  xpathExpression = "//branch-area[@name]";
            NodeList list = (NodeList) XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate(xpathExpression,inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);                     
            for(int i=0; i<list.getLength();i+=1)
            {       
                System.out.println(list.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());    
            }
```

but i am getting an empty string can you please tell me where i am wrong ?

Comment: Partial duplicate - there's more to this question than just the XPath expression.

Answer (score 4):

`//branch-area[@name]` will return element nodes - those `branch-area` elements that have a `name` attribute. If you want the attribute nodes themselves then use

```
//branch-area/@name
```

and you don't need the `getFirstChild()` in the loop, as attribute nodes hold the value directly rather than having text node children.